# Problems with content search in div with Selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have problems to press this type of buttons with Selenium since the name by which I look for "5dbnhpbwuny6rmr65h86" and the button are in different div in Python.

Complete HTML code: https://codeshare.io/a39b3g.

[Image HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVP1o.png).

Example HTML code:

```
<div class="o_kanban_view o_kanban_dashboard o_pos_kanban o_cannot_create o_kanban_ungrouped" style="display: flex;"><div class="o_kanban_record">
                            <div class="o_kanban_card_header">
                                <div class="o_kanban_card_header_title">
                                    <div class="o_primary">5dbnhpbwuny6rmr65h86</div>
                                    <div class="o_secondary">Unused</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="o_kanban_manage_button_section">
                                    <a class="o_kanban_manage_toggle_button" href="#">Más <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="container o_kanban_card_content o_visible">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 o_kanban_primary_left">






                <button class="btn btn-default oe_kanban_action oe_kanban_action_button" data-name="open_session_cb" data-type="object" type="button">New Session
                </button>
            </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 o_kanban_primary_right">




                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div><div class="container o_kanban_card_manage_pane o_invisible">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 o_kanban_card_manage_section o_kanban_manage_view">
                                        <div class="o_kanban_card_manage_title">
                                            <span>Ver</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <a data-name="341" data-type="action" href="#" class=" oe_kanban_action oe_kanban_action_a">Sesiones</a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <a data-name="342" data-type="action" href="#" class=" oe_kanban_action oe_kanban_action_a">Pedidos de ventas</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 o_kanban_card_manage_section o_kanban_manage_new">
                                        <div class="o_kanban_card_manage_title">
                                            <span>Informes</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <a data-name="343" data-type="action" href="#" class=" oe_kanban_action oe_kanban_action_a">Pedidos</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="o_kanban_card_manage_settings row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 text-right">
                                        <a data-type="edit" href="#" class=" oe_kanban_action oe_kanban_action_a">Configuración</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><div class="o_kanban_record o_kanban_ghost"></div><div class="o_kanban_record o_kanban_ghost"></div><div class="o_kanban_record o_kanban_ghost"></div><div class="o_kanban_record o_kanban_ghost"></div><div class="o_kanban_record o_kanban_ghost"></div><div class="o_kanban_record o_kanban_ghost"></div></div>
```

I came up with something like that, but I do not have the right solution:

```
for div in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='o_kanban_record']"):

  if div.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(text() , '5dbnhpbwuny6rmr65h86')]") != []:

    div.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(text() , 'New Session')]").click()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you update the Question with the HTML as formatted text instead of a image for better analysis?

Comment: @DebanjanB - I can not put the complete code, I upload a fragment

Comment: The string `iuijg6bzr2xs9gsueq2i` is not present in your HTML, seems the string `iuijg6bzr2xs9gsueq2i` is dynamic. Can you sum up the manual steps you are trying to Automate?

Comment: The string "iuijg6bzr2xs9gsueq2i" is not dynamic, it is a random name created by another selenium for a store, what I want to do is search for the name of a store and press the button of the new session. In the full HTML, if you find "iuijg6bzr2xs9gsueq2i", edit the code split and thank you for your help @DebanjanB - Image: https://ibb.co/b1kNv6

Comment: random is dynamic. And the string really is not present in the HTML code that you provided.

Comment: 2 Questions - 1) What exactly do you mean by `a random name created by another selenium` for the string `iuijg6bzr2xs9gsueq2i`? 2) Where can I find the `name of a store`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `click()` on the `New Session` button for any of the `Strings` e.g. 
**iuijg6bzr2xs9gsueq2i** or **5dbnhpbwuny6rmr65h86**, you can take help of a function and pass any `String` to get the relevant `New Session` button clicked.

The final solution, which detects the state of the button is:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='o_primary' and contains(text(), '%s')]/parent::div[*]/parent::div[*]/parent::div[*]/descendant::button[@data-name='open_session_cb']" % (shop))[0].click()
```

OR

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='o_primary' and contains(text(), '%s')]/parent::div[*]/parent::div[*]/parent::div[*]/descendant::button[@data-name='open_ui']" % (shop))[0].click()
```

Comment: Your solution is perfect, it's cleaner

Answer (score 1):

1. Get all divs and buttons:

   ```
   divs = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".o_primary") 
   buttons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".btn.btn-default.oe_kanban_action.oe_kanban_action_button")
   ```
2. Go through the list of div elements and find needed one and do click action on the appropriate button:

   ```
   for div, button in zip(divs, buttons):

     if div.text == "5dbnhpbwuny6rmr65h86":

       button.click()
   ```

Comment: That sounds good, but I have: `TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration` I need a list in variable?

Comment: @jbelenus, sorry, that was my mistake. I have updated my answer. Try on again.

Comment: I did not know the use of zip, I already learned it for the process. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about [Splinter](http://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/why.html)? It is an abstraction layer on top of Selenium and it allows you to find elements by text: https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/finding.html

```
driver.find_by_text('5dbnhpbwuny6rmr65h86')
```

find_by_text returns a **list** of elements,so it should be

```
element = driver.find_by_text('5dbnhpbwuny6rmr65h86').first
element.find_by_xpath("//button[contains(text() , 'New Session')]").first.click()
```

Note: Untested